# Can't connect to rpi with either minicom or gnu screen when connecting with console cable

Tags: gpio, terminal, serial-console

I already patched GNU screen so I made it past the 'loginName too long', but now I can connect, nothing shows up. I installed the driver as instructed [here](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/software-installation-mac). Directly after I downloaded the driver from the above link it did work, the next time it showed all scrambled letters and now it doesn't show anything. I tried minicom as well, but that didn't work either, it only showed scrambled characters (not even alphabetic, sometimes). How to get either of them to work? I am sure that Raspian boots up normally, as I can still SSH into the pi.

Comment: How are you powering the Pi? Via the cable or via Micro-USB? Try not connecting the red lead, powering it by the micro-USB. Power problem for the port possibly?

Comment: Great! Looking good: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QHmb9.png

Comment: Um, I forgot to notify you. @RPiAwesomeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@11684's problem was solved by my comment, as you can see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/cant-connect-to-rpi-with-either-minicom-or-gnu-screen-when-connecting-with-cons?noredirect=1#comment16808_9933).

Just posting this as answer so he can mark it as answer and get this officially answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing scrambled characters, it may just be the baud rate is wrong

Have a look at your `/boot/cmdline.txt` to see what baud rate is specified there. Usually it's 115200

Other settings to check are

8 bit/no parity

Make sure you have the ground wire connected between the PL2303 and the RPi

Comment: Ground wire? And what do you mean with PL2302?

Comment: Sorry, that should be PL2303. It's the chip that does the USB-serial conversion. Can you take a picture of your setup?